# Cannot import package despite dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Added the url of the repo that where Im pulling the jar from as well as its dependencies. I then tried to import it in my project, but despite that, I am not getting anywhere. The import is failing in this case
Here is the pom and a sample of code

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.osm_query</groupId>
  <artifactId>osm_query</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>osm_query</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>clojars</id>
    <url>https://clojars.org/repo/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>tangrammer</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-net-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

the project and its jars

[image]